# Does the number of decimal places in coordinates affect the speed of rendering of the features on a Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

I am trying to improve the performance of a webpage that renders hundreds of points on a Leaflet map. I noticed that the coordinates of these points are saved and retrieved with unnecessary accuracy (14 decimal places). I wonder if limiting the decimal places to 5, which is enough for my purpose, should (and if, why?) impact the speed of rendering of the map with features.

Comment: I don't think that this will affect the performance. I suggest you to use canvas renderer and ther markercluster-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the number of *relevant* decimal places used in numbers do not matter.

In Javascript*, all numbers are stored as [64-bit IEEE-754 floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). No matter how many base-10 relevant digits you see, internally there's always a 52-bit mantissa.

(* I mean, non-WebGL, non-`Float32Array` Javascript, which is the case for Leaflet. Since using anything else than float64 datatypes in Javascript is cumbersome, this kind of low-level optimizations is seldom done).

What you want to do is a case of premature optimization. The important figure to keep in mind is not the number of CPU cycles per arithmetic operation (which [is lower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#FLOPs_per_cycle_per_core_for_various_processors) for float32 than for float64 registers in modern [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit)s), but the [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for the complexity of the algorithms being used.

Comment: I guess this is not the kind of answer that a forestry person *needs*, but it's the kind of answer that a compsci person *can give*. :-)

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. The forestry person appreciates the answer :)

Comment: Your understanding is appreciated :-) BTW, since you seem to be new, I'll point out that [upvoting an answer is not the same as accepting an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).